# How to integrate Hotdocs word templates with K2 five to generate the final completed document?

Tags: document, service-broker, k2

Trying to set up the K2 smartobjects to connect to Hotdocs Rest Apis which can return the word template. But I am unable to find proper Rest service options in K2.
What should be the approach to make them work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you that you use REST service broker and configure it with hotdocs swagger file available to download from https://core.hotdocshub.com/swagger/ui/index. Once you create the service instance, you will be able to create SmartObjects for the methods of the REST API.

Comment: if you may suggest, how can we generate xml string from K2 smartforms ?

Comment: @STforever if my answer was helpful, may I ask you to mark it as answer?

Comment: @STforever regarding XML: Can you write more details? Perhaps as a separate question so that other members also benefit from the discussion, and I will happy to provide guidance - you can tag me in comment once you post the question.